# Power BI - Can you break down a certain bar within a bar chart?

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart

I am creating a bar graph in Power BI and was wondering if it is possible to breakdown a certain bar in the bar graph (like a stacked bar) by a category.

Here is the end result that I am trying to achieve.
[image]

The 'other' category is the only one broken down. Whereas the others are not. Is this possible?! Anyone please help if it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you will need to prepare your data for that. For example break the values for your general data, Browser A and Browser B into different columns. Create a total column and use that as a sort for the Category.

Then create a stacked horizontal column chart with all three number columns (Browser A, Browser B, and General) in the values.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.